# Cluster high performing SKU's based on frequency of Order together and Quantity Ordered

Tags: spss, excel, spss-modeler

I have list of order numbers, each containing ordered SKU's(One order may have multiple SKU's) and their ordered Quantities. Now after initial analysis I found that 16/550 SKU;s are there in 50% Orders. Also 5 or more of these 16 SKU's are there in 20% orders. 
Question: I want to identify top 15-20 SKU's which are present in most of Orders in significant volume(High Quantity). I heard about cluster analysis can cluster these high perfroming SKU's. Can anyone help how to find these high performig SKU's? This concept is known as forward area in warehousing.
Thanks
Source:
Sample Raw data
Material Code,  Delivery Number,    Quantity ordered

Thanks

Comment: I think you may need to clarify what the statistical question is here as opposed to the programming one. All your tags are about software.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into association rules.  These are available in Statistics via the SPSSINC APRIORI extension command.  That requires the R Essentials for Statistics.